# Quickfix and building a CMake project on windows

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, quickfix, filetype-cmake

I'm trying to get to the point where I can build a CMake project in neovim and have it output a quickfix list that I can quickly step through.  In Visual Studio, I would typically hit CTRL+b for build, and use F8 to step through errors.  That's what I'm aiming for.  When I run a command line such as this:

```
:ASyncRun cmake --build .
```

I see the following in my quickfix window:

```
|| [cmake --build .]
|| Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.2.0-preview.19264.2+c3389964c for .NET Framework
|| Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
|| 
||   Checking Build System
```

I'm not sure why I get the || at the beginning of each line, but they are obviously messing up the quickfix, because :cn, etc. just steps through every line.
I was hoping for just a list of error lines that I could step through.

Any tips for getting this to work on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to change my errorformat for VC.  Here's what I did:

```
" Thanks to https://forums.handmadehero.org/index.php/forum?view=topic&catid=4&id=704#3982
" error message formats
" Microsoft MSBuild
set errorformat+=\\\ %#%f(%l\\\,%c):\ %m
" Microsoft compiler: cl.exe
set errorformat+=\\\ %#%f(%l)\ :\ %#%t%[A-z]%#\ %m
" Microsoft HLSL compiler: fxc.exe
set errorformat+=\\\ %#%f(%l\\\,%c-%*[0-9]):\ %#%t%[A-z]%#\ %m
```